# When I remove the first column, row.names are removed too?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('row1','row2','row3'),col2=c(1,1,1),col3=c(0,0.5,2))
> row.names(df) <- df$col1
> df
     col1 col2 col3
row1 row1    1  0.0
row2 row2    1  0.5
row3 row3    1  2.0
> df <- select(df, -starts_with("col1"))
> df
     col2 col3
row1    1  0.0
row2    1  0.5
row3    1  2.0
```

What I did above is not functioning with my real code. So I have a data.frame in R. I make the first column the row.names. Now I want to remove the first column but when I do this, the row.names are removed too (an get converted into numbering).
Unfortunately I can´t reproduce my mistake. With `df` it works well how it should. With my data it looks like this

```
     col2 col3
   1   1  0.0
   2   1  0.5
   3   1  2.0
```

What is a reason (and solution) for that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you check if the result is a `tibble` ? These don't support rownames afaik.

Comment: Do you do any `filter` operation in your dplyr chain? If so, then your data.frame would be converted to a tibble and tibbles don't have rownames.

Comment: Yes,it was a tibble. Simply with ```df <- as.data.frame(df)``` I could solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply deselect `col1`:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('row1','row2','row3'),col2=c(1,1,1),col3=c(0,0.5,2))
row.names(df) <- df$col1
```

Subset `df` by deselecting `col1`:

```
df[,-1]
     col2 col3
row1    1  0.0
row2    1  0.5
row3    1  2.0
```